# Swift init UIViewController from different xib crash

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller

```
let xibs = ["UpdatePasswdViewController","FeedBackViewController",...]
let xibName = self.xibs[indexPath.row]
let pushVc: UIViewController = UIViewController.init(nibName: xibName, bundle: nil)
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(pushVc, animated: true)


class UpdatePasswdViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var confirmNewPasswdTextField: UITextField!
}
```

'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key confirmNewPasswdTextField.'
*** First throw call stack:

When init like this,it's ok.But I have many viewController in xibs array.

`let pushVc: UpdatePasswdViewController = UpdatePasswdViewController.init(nibName: "UpdatePasswdViewController", bundle:nil)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your problem comes from using the `UIViewController` version of `init` instead of creating an object of the subclass your want.  Here's some test code that should help you to get what you want:

```
    let moduleName = "XibSwift"
    let xibs = ["TestViewController"]

    let controllerClass: AnyClass? = NSClassFromString("\(moduleName).\(xibs[0])")
    if let realControllerClass = controllerClass as! UIViewController.Type? {
        let vc = realControllerClass.init(nibName: xibs[0], bundle: nil)
        print(vc)
    }
```

Comment: The const `moduleName` mean what?

Comment: An app or framework name: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AccessControl.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH41-ID3